# How to Set this in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following setup:

```
var Dash = {
    nextIndex: 0,
    dashboards: <some value>,

    display: function()
    {
        var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];
        document.getElementById("iframe3").src = dashboard.url;
        Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
        setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
    }
};
```

With this setup, is it possible to set programmatically, the value of "some value" prior to this declaration?

In addition, is it possible to have  be a javascript function call that retunrs a value to dashboards?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Give us some more background to work with.

Comment: I am basically trying to pre-populate <some_value> with a list of urls depending on some criteria but unfortunately when I try and do this, the initial value of some_value is null and I get a javascript error.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Not *prior* (short of dummy values like null) but you can do so afterwards using `Dash.dashboards= some-value;`

Answer (score 1):

No.

You would have to define `Dash` in order to define `Dash.dashboards`, and as soon as your listed code runs it is all overwritten.

So, no.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has lexical scoping and not block scoping . What that means is that all variable declaration in javascript are shifted to the top of the function .

So the code that you wrote is internally changed to something like :

```
    var Dash = undefined ;
   // other lines of codes 
    Dash = {
        nextIndex: 0,
        dashboards: some_value,

        display: function()
        {
            var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];
            document.getElementById("iframe3").src = dashboard.url;
            Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
            setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
        }
    };
```

So you basically want to access the value of `Dash.dashboard` before `Dash` is assigned, which would fail as `Dash` is undefined . and `undefined.dashboard` would give you an error . 
However you could definitely call a function in the assignment operation that populates `some_value`

```
var Dash = {
        dashboards: function_call()
}
```

Btw , why exactly would you want to use Dash.dashboard before the assignment operation ? If you could let us know that , there might be a better way of doing it .

Answer (score 1):

You can not . Dash would be undefined until it is assigned . so Dash.dashboard would not be accesible .

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
dashboards: null,
```

Answer (score 0):

To set some value to dashboards

```
Dash.dashboards = "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

As dashboards is going to hold an array I would use an empty array: `dashbords: []`